# How should I handle queuing wcf messages?

Tags: .net, wcf

I am implementing a WCF service based on a 3rd party WSDL.  Rather than process the messages synchronously, I want to dump the xml into a database, and have it processed by another part process.  Is using the WCF Message class directly the right way to go ab out this?  Or should I just let WCF deserialize the message and the re-serialize so I can put it in the database?

To clarify, I can't use the WCF MSMQ binding because the 3rd party has dictated this will be a soap web service.  I just want to queue the messages on my end somehow so the processing can by asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you possibly use [MSMQ](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/msmq/default.mspx) ? That's the classic message-queueing system, and it's supported by WCF.

You could receive the message from that third-party service and then just put it in the MSMQ for later processing.

As for message vs. deserialized object: both will work ok, but I think having a real .NET object is a bit easier to deal with.

Some more info:

- [How to: Exchange Messages with WCF Endpoints and Message Queuing Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789008.aspx)
- [WCF Sample Starter Project on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCF_MSMQ_Integration.aspx)
- [WCF and MSMQ—Take a Message](http://www.devx.com/architect/Article/41058)
- [Tom Hollander: MSMQ, WCF and IIS: Getting them to play nice](http://blogs.msdn.com/tomholl/archive/2008/07/12/msmq-wcf-and-iis-getting-them-to-play-nice-part-1.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reponse.  Unless I misunderstand, the server would have to be msmq as well right?  The server side is already defined, it has to be a soap web service.

Comment: So you're connecting to a third-party server you cannot influence? No problem - you get the message / object from the remote server in your client app, and then you stick it into a MSMQ queue for later processing, and just return back a e.g. confirmation number or something to the third-party. Would that work?

Comment: Yes, that would work, I'm just trying to understand if I have to let wcf deserialize the message or if I can grab the message before that and stick it in the queue.

Comment: Robin: you can do both; I find working with deserialized .NET objects easier than dealing with the low-level "Message" class directly.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you want them to go to the DB at all?  Investigating MSMQ as an applicable alternative might be smart here... this way it is closer to a config change, rather than a lot of custom development.

If you *do* need to do this, I would recommend creating a custom channel stack (both client and server) for the purpose.  Then, yes, you would simply be serializing and deserializing the Message.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The server is 3rd party and is not going to change, so that is not a possibility.